# How to install 64 bit Lubuntu 16.04.3 on Lenovo Z570?

Tags: dual-boot, lubuntu, uefi, lenovo

I now run Windows 10 Pro 1709 on my Lenovo Z570 laptop; Lenovo System Update shows no new software updates for the Z570. I used [unetbootin-windows-657](https://unetbootin.github.io/) to create Live Lubuntu on USB flash drive. I then tried to install from it. This worked for 32 bit Lubuntu.

For 64 bit Lubuntu in BIOS compatible mode, Lubuntu kernel crashed (can't find init) and Windows no longer booted. I created new GPT partitions using Live Lubuntu gparted, and reinstalled Windows with Recovery and EFI System partitions. Now I get this error message:

```
acer_wmi: Unsupported machine has AMW0_GUID1, unable to load.
```

Torvalds GitHub source for `acer-wmi.c` includes Lenovo 3000 N200 on the quirks list, but not Lenovo Z570.

Answer (score 1):

A change in my GPT partitions solved the problem. /dev/sda2 is the Microsoft EFI partition, which I identified as a FAT32 partition. When I re-installed Lubuntu, gparted identified /dev/sda2 as an EFI system partition with flags boot,esp and the installer used that partition for Microsoft and Ubuntu boot information. Apparently this change allowed the installer to access the correct WMI driver. I also flagged the Microsoft reserved partition (/dev/sda3) as bios_grub.

Comment: Correction: I discovered the problem was only postponed. After doing several "Software Updater" cycles, the problem has returned. I am now on Linux 4.13.0-26-generic.

Comment: Another possibility: my Insider Preview may have corrupted the update process by continually changing my computer to London time (8 hour difference). It did break the Cygwin make command (could not find shared library object file), and I had to re-install my entire Cygwin distribution.

Comment: Can someone with more knowledge of kernel drivers and the update process explain what is happening?